# Are there better ways of structuring things and also question regarding routing/MaterialApp

Tags: flutter, firebase, bloc, flutter-go-router, get-it

[image: app architecture]

I made a simple snapshot of my app architecture so far. I am learning flutter on my own and i would like to hear from experts if this is good so far? my biggest decisions that so far were where to place the authStateChanges stream from firebase (not sure if i should do it inside the AuthBloc or in UserService per example or something else). Also get_it is only useful to register singletons i guess? if i want a class with parameters its probably better to just do it normally?

and one last question which troubles me a lot so far. from my understanding when i navigate routes i will always have as the root widget the widget that contains the materialapp that has routes as parameter right? in this case, every time i push and go to routes it will have Home as root widget always?